# Regex function to allow special characterss

Tags: apex, administration

How to use regex function to allow special characters like below

```
(( REGEX( Name ,  "^[a-zA-Z0-9_ + < = > % & * " ' ( ) ,  . / : ; ? $ [\ #  ] @ -]*$")))
```

Is this valid?

Comment: Do you ONLY want to allow special characters, meaning no numbers and no letters? What is that you're trying to validate?

Comment: Nope. i want to allow alphabets,numbers and above mentioned special characters. Trying to validate Name field

Comment: I guess that will work. Are there any characters that you're trying to prevent from input? If so, wouldn't be better to check for invalid characters rather than having this long regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only the reserved regular expression keywords mentioned below will
>   have weird effects since these keywords internally have their own
>   functionality to accomplish

```
     . ^ $ * + - ? ( ) [ ] { } \ |
```

- All Special characters you mentioned will not break your regex format.
- So whenever you come across one of these regular expression reserved characters use backslash `\` to escape it.
- For example lets assume all the sequence characters above appears in string and we need to escape it. Then in Regex it should be written as

  ```
   \. \^ \$ \* \+ -\ \? \( \) \[ \] \{ \} \\ \|
  ```

**Note:**

- Backslash `\` itself is escaped with another backslash  `\\`